# Conditional in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jcombobox, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create an app that moves a shape left and right depending on the button pushed. I have an `int shapesCond` and `int colorsCond` that changes value depending on which option is selected from my `JComboBox`.

If I only change the value for `shapesCond` in the "Rectangle" option of the `JComboBox`, and not in the "Circle" option, a rectangle is printed. But if I change the `shapesCond` values in both options or change the `colorsCond` values, my `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method won't print any shapes.

```
public class DrawShapes extends JFrame {
    public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 300;
    public static final Color CANVAS_BACKGROUND = Color.YELLOW;
    private int x1 = CANVAS_WIDTH / 4;
    private int y1 = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 4;
    private int rectWidth = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
    private int rectHeight = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;
    private int x2 = CANVAS_WIDTH * (1/3);
    private int y2 = CANVAS_HEIGHT * (2/5);
    private int circWidth = CANVAS_WIDTH * (1/5);
    private int circHeight = CANVAS_HEIGHT / 3;
    private Color blue = new Color(0, 0, 225);
    private int shapesCond = 0;
    private int colorsCond = 0;

    private CanvasDrawArea canvas;

public DrawShapes() {
JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

String[] shapeName = {"Rectangle", "Circle"};
JComboBox shapes = new JComboBox(shapeName);
shapes.setSelectedIndex(1);
btnPanel.add(shapes);
shapes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ //shapes combobox
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource(); //copies shapes combo box
         String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            switch(msg){
                case "Rectangle":
                     shapesCond = 1;
                     break;
                case "Circle":
                     shapesCond = 2;
            }//switch end
    }
}); //action listener end

String[] colorName = {"Red", "Blue", "Green"}; 
    JComboBox colors = new JComboBox(colorName); //colors combobox
    colors.setSelectedIndex(1);
    btnPanel.add(colors);
    shapes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource(); //copies shapes combo box
            String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            switch(msg){
                case "Red" :
                    colorsCond = 1;
                    break;
                case "Blue" :
                    colorsCond = 2;
                    break;
                case "Green" :
                    colorsCond = 3;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
canvas = new CanvasDrawArea();
canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));

Container cp = getContentPane();
cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
cp.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
cp.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setTitle("Drawing Shapes: Moving Shapes");
pack(); 
setVisible(true); 
requestFocus(); 
}//DrawShapes constructor end

class CanvasDrawArea extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (shapesCond == 1 && colorsCond == 1) { //red rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(x1, y1, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            repaint();
        }
        if (shapesCond == 1 && colorsCond == 2) { //blue rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(x1, y1, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            repaint();
        }
        if (shapesCond == 1 && colorsCond == 3) { //green rectangle
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x1, y1, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            repaint();
        }
        if (shapesCond == 2 && colorsCond == 1) { // red circle
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x2, y2, circWidth, circHeight);
            repaint();
        }
        if (shapesCond == 2 && colorsCond == 2) { //blue circle
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(x2, y2, circWidth, circHeight);
            repaint();
        }
        if (shapesCond == 2 && colorsCond == 3) { //green circle
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(x2, y2, circWidth, circHeight);
            repaint();
        }  
    }//paintComponent method end
}//CanvasDrawArea class end
}//DrawShapes class end
```

And then here's my main method. It's in a separate class called `Main`.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DrawShapes(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses - oh, don't call `repaint` from within any `paint` method...

Comment: Your code makes no sense, you have functionality outside of methods, there's no clear definition of class boundaries and it makes it impossible to understand the flow of the logic.  Repost a **runnable** example

Comment: Okay, copy and paste that code into an IDE (or text file) and see if you can make it compile... `}//constructor end` followed by a bunch of code, followed by ` }//DrawShapes constructor end` is very worrisome...I mean, which constructor are we actually dealing with here...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That was my bad, I don't know why I had two constructor ends. I think I must have forgotten to take one out when I edited my code.

Comment: As @MadProgrammer said, you should not be calling repaint in the paintComponent method. You should be calling it at the end of the actionPerformed, as that's when you want the update to occur

Comment: Also make use of the [Shape API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). Have a class level `Shape` that you use as the _only_ object to draw. Then just use a custom `setShape(Shape)` method to set the class member Shape instance. You can also call repaint from _that_ method. Look at all the subclass/implementations you can choose from (i.e. Rectangle, Ellipse). Also make use of the [`Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) API for easy `draw(Shape)` and `fill(Shape)` methods `Graphics2D` can be cast to `Graphics`.

Comment: .. i.e. `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; g2d.fill(rectangle);` You can use the same technique mentioned above (for the shape) to set the color. This will also help you avoid all the `if` combinations, which will lead to cleaner code

Comment: @peeskillet Yep, pretty much mentioned that in the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373449/jcombobox-change-shapes-and-colors), haven't been able to drag that across the line yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`circWidth` is `0`...`1 / 5` is a integer division, meaning that the trailing decimals are trimmed off, meaing it's equal to `0`, so `0 * anything` is `0`...

You could use something like `(int)(CANVAS_WIDTH * (1 / 5f))` instead...

You're adding the `ActionListener` for the `colors` combobox to the `shapes` combobox...

```
JComboBox colors = new JComboBox(colorName); //colors combobox
colors.setSelectedIndex(1);
btnPanel.add(colors);
shapes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
```

It would be better to place `shapes.setSelectedIndex(1);` and `colors.setSelectedIndex(1);` after the registration of the `ActionListener`s, this will allow them to trigger the `ActionListener`s and prime the initial values...

The `if` statements in the `paintComponent` method could be changed to something more like...

```
switch (colorsCond) {
    case 1:
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
    case 3:
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
}
switch (shapesCond) {
    case 1:
        g.fillRect(x1, y1, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.fillOval(x2, y2, circWidth, circHeight);
        break;
}
```

Which would reduce the code clutter and repeation and make it easier what is suppose to be happening...

At the end of your `actionPerformed` methods, you need to call `repaint`

And just for comparison...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawShapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawShapes();
    }

    public DrawShapes() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DrawingPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DrawingPane extends JPanel {

        private JComboBox cbShape;
        private JComboBox cbColor;
        private CanvasPane canvasPane;

        public DrawingPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            canvasPane = new CanvasPane();

            JPanel controls = new JPanel();
            cbShape = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Rectangle", "Circle"});
            cbColor = new JComboBox(new ColorEntry[]{
                new ColorEntry("Red", Color.RED), 
                new ColorEntry("Green", Color.GREEN), 
                new ColorEntry("Blue", Color.BLUE), 
                new ColorEntry("Magenta", Color.MAGENTA)});
            cbColor.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

                @Override
                public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                    if (value instanceof ColorEntry) {
                        Color color = ((ColorEntry)value).getColor();
                        setBackground(color);
                        setOpaque(true);
                    }
                    return this;
                }

            });
            JButton apply = new JButton("Apply");
            apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    CustomShape shape = null;
                    ColorEntry entry = (ColorEntry) cbColor.getSelectedItem();
                    Color color = entry == null ? null : entry.getColor();
                    if (color != null) {
                        int width = canvasPane.getWidth() / 2;
                        int height = canvasPane.getHeight() / 2;
                        switch (cbShape.getSelectedIndex()) {
                            case 0: {
                                int x = (canvasPane.getWidth() - width) / 2;
                                int y = (canvasPane.getHeight() - height) / 2;
                                shape = new CustomRectangle(x, y, width, height, color);
                            }
                            break;
                            case 1: {
                                int diameter = Math.min(width, height);
                                int x = (canvasPane.getWidth() - diameter) / 2;
                                int y = (canvasPane.getHeight() - diameter) / 2;
                                shape = new CustomCircle(x, y, diameter, color);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    canvasPane.setShape(shape);
                }
            });
            controls.add(cbShape);
            controls.add(cbColor);
            controls.add(apply);

            add(canvasPane);
            add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

    }

    public class ColorEntry {

        private String name;
        private Color color;

        public ColorEntry(String name, Color color) {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

    }

    public class CanvasPane extends JPanel {

        private CustomShape shape;

        public CanvasPane() {
        }

        public void setShape(CustomShape shape) {
            this.shape = shape;
            repaint();
        }

        public CustomShape getShape() {
            return shape;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (shape != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                shape.paint(g2d);
            }
        }

    }

    public interface CustomShape {

        public Rectangle getBounds();

        public Color getColor();

        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);

    }

    public abstract class AbstractCustomShape implements CustomShape {

        private Rectangle bounds;
        private Color color;

        @Override
        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
            this.bounds = bounds;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

    }

    public class CustomRectangle extends AbstractCustomShape {

        public CustomRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
            setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            setColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(getColor());
            g2d.fill(getBounds());
        }

    }

    public class CustomCircle extends AbstractCustomShape {

        public CustomCircle(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color) {
            setBounds(new Rectangle(x, y, diameter, diameter));
            setColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(getColor());
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
            g2d.fill(circle);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me with this problem.  I changed the values for the circWidth and circHeight to be real numbers. Now both shapes print out perfectly.  The problem now is that the code you wrote changes the shapes but the colors are all gray. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I made so many changes to your code.  You need to add `repaint` at the end of the `actionPerformed` methods...

Comment: I don't quite understand everything that you wrote but I really appreciate you spending so much of your time helping me with this problem.  I will definitely go over this code and see if I can figure out what you did.

Comment: I don't understand much of it either ;)